# Create always on top notification on Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, notifications

Is there a way to implement this (see picture) as a normal Human or is this a feature that can only be used by google/chrome?

Steps to reproduce:
When there is a running WM Game type "WM" in google and there is the option to pin a specific game. The Notification then stays on top until you delete it. Even out of chrome. And it updates when the game progresses.

Is there a way to implement this in a normal website?

[image: Floating Always on Top Notification about WM]

Comment: When you say always on top, do you mean that as you scroll, the notification stays at the top of your screen and is always showing?

Comment: it stays where it is and i can drag it around (like the floating facebook-messenger icon) even if i leave chrome
so,yes